# Automated UI testing on remote computers without installing anything remotely

Tags: testing, record, qtp

Which options do we have to do automated UI testing on remote computers connected via RDP, if I don't want to install anything on the remote computer?

My only idea is to open the rdp session always in the same way and use recorded mouse and key strokes, but there are some disadvantages, e.g. I assume it's slow?

Anyways, do you know any open source or proprietary tools I can use? Best would be that I have to install nothing on the remote machine and play the record on my local machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting with UFT 11.50 (previously known as QTP) there is support for image based testing.

You can have one machine with UFT installed and replay on other machines via RDP using [`Insight` UFT's image based automation solution](http://h30499.www3.hp.com/t5/The-Future-of-Testing-Blog/A-guide-to-Image-Based-Testing-with-HP-UFT-s-Insight/ba-p/6355855).

Answer (score 1):

eggPlant Functional allows you to automate the UI of any app on Windows machines using an RDP connection. It's pretty fast assuming you are connecting over a decent network, and you don't need to install anything additional on the target machine.